# Is Wikipedia's definition of $\omega$-inconsistency problematic in this way?

Tags: logic, definition

I could be wrong, but the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#Definition) of $\omega$-inconsistency given at over Wikipedia seems slightly problematic. In particular, Wikipedia claims that $\omega$-inconsistency is a property of a theory $T$, but it seems to me that its actually a property of a pair $(\eta,T)$ where $T$ is a theory and $\eta$ is an interpretation of arithmetic in $T$. The problem is, a theory $T$ can interpret arithmetic in more than one way, I think.

Is this correct, or am I misreading the definition? Here's a copy and paste.

> A theory $T$ is said to interpret the language of arithmetic if there
>   is a translation of formulas of arithmetic into the language of $T$ so
>   that $T$ is able to prove the basic axioms of the natural numbers
>   under this translation.
>
> A $T$ that interprets arithmetic is $\omega$-inconsistent if, for some
>   property $P$ of natural numbers (defined by a formula in the language
>   of $T$), $T$ proves $P(0)$, $P(1)$, $P(2)$, and so on (that is, for
>   every standard natural number $n$, $T$ proves that $P(n)$ holds), but
>   $T$ also proves that there is some (necessarily nonstandard) natural
>   number $n$ such that $P(n)$ fails.

Comment: Yes, without the interpretation $T$ cannot even express $\exists n\neg P(n)$. But the phrase "A $T$ that interprets arithmetic" may be understood as "A pair $(T,\eta)$ of a theory $T$ together with an interpretation $\eta$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question is not marked as unanswered:

> Yes, without the interpretation $T$ cannot even express $\exists n \lnot P(n)$. But the phrase "A $T$ that interprets arithmetic" may be understood as "A pair $(T,η)$ of a theory $T$ together with an interpretation $η$". – Hagen von Eitzen Aug 13 at 14:42